# How to replace the name of document in document library with it's title in view?

Tags: document-library, view

How to change the link to a document (which shows the name of the document) in document library to a link which shows the title of the document instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010 you can edit the page with the list view in SharePoint Designer. In Design view, click the field you want to change and use the fly-out menu to tick the options to show the list item menu and/or the link to the item.

[image]

If you don't have design view you can add `LinkToItem="TRUE"` to the field name in the ViewFields tag in code view.

```
        <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/>
            <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Title" LinkToItem="TRUE"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>

        </ViewFields>
```